# undefined reference to `vtable [CMakeLists.txt] (Unit Testing)

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm getting several errors when conducting my unit test. My goal is to see if my make->shipCost() will be equal to the expected.

```
TEST(FactoryTestSet, USNShipCost) {
    USN_Fleet_Factory* makeAShip; 
    USN_Ship *make; 
    makeAShip = new USN_Ship_Factory;
    make = makeAShip->CreateAircraftCarrier("Aircraft Carrier");
    EXPECT_EQ(make->shipCost(), 8); 
    make = makeAShip->CreateCruiser("Cruiser");
    EXPECT_EQ(make->shipCost(), 5); 
    make = makeAShip->CreateDestroyer("Destroyer");
    EXPECT_EQ(make->shipCost(), 3); 
    make = makeAShip->CreateFrigate("Frigate");
    EXPECT_EQ(make->shipCost(), 2); 
}

TEST(FactoryTestSet, PLANShipCost) {
    PLAN_Fleet_Factory* makeAVessel; 
    PLAN_Ship *assemble; 
    makeAVessel = new PLAN_Ship_Factory;
    assemble = makeAVessel->CreateAircraftCarrier("Aircraft Carrier");
    EXPECT_EQ(assemble->shipCost(), 8); 
    assemble = makeAVessel->CreateCruiser("Cruiser");
    EXPECT_EQ(assemble->shipCost(), 4); 
    assemble = makeAVessel->CreateDestroyer("Destroyer");
    EXPECT_EQ(assemble->shipCost(), 3);
    assemble = makeAVessel->CreateFrigate("Frigate");
    EXPECT_EQ(assemble->shipCost(), 1);
}
```

Example of what one of my base subclasses looks like:

```
class GF_Class_Aircraft_Carrier : public USN_Ship{
private:
    int shipPrice = 8;
    int PI = 10;
public:
    void accept(Visitor &v); 
    virtual void ShipName() {std::cout << "- USS Gerald R. Ford\n";}
    virtual void shipHullNumber() {std::cout << "- CVN-75\n";}
    void shipClassName() {std::cout << "- Gerald Ford Class Aircraft Carrier\n";}
    void shipType() {std::cout << "- Aircraft Carrier\n";}
    void arament() {std::cout << "- 40 F-35 Lightning's, 10 E-8 Growler Hornet's, 8 SH-60 Seahawk's\n";}
    int shipCost() {std::cout << "- Ship Cost:$" << shipPrice << " billion\n"; return shipPrice;}
    int powerIndex() {return PI;}
    virtual void assignHomePort() {std::cout << "- Home Port:  \n";}
    virtual void assignAdmiral() {std::cout << "- Commanding Officer:  \n";}

};
```

Comment: Post text not images thanks - ideally of a [mcve]

Comment: You probably have a class with virtual function that are not abstract but are also not implemented. If you declare a virtual function you either need to make it abstract, or defined (implement) it.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Just post the _text_ as text inside the question.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the questions so that their are now no images.

Comment: Also please edit your question to include the full and complete error output (also as text). And you need to look through *all* your classes for unimplemented virtual functions.